# Unable to run loops on dataframe after merging

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, yfinance

I have two stock prices datasets. The first, `df_y`, is my dependent variable and is a univariate series of S&P 500 opening stock prices.

```
df_y=yf.download('^GSPC', start='1991-10-9', end='2021-10-7', progress=False) 
df_y=df_y.drop(["Close", "High", "Low", "Adj Close", "Volume"], axis=1)
df_y = df_y.rename(columns={'Open': '(Open, ^GSPC)'})
```

The second, `df_x` is a matrix of independent variables and contains several stock variables from the NASDAQ and Dow Jones indices:

```
df_x=yf.download(['^IXIC','DJI'], start='1991-10-9', end='2021-10-7', progress=False) 
df_x=df_x.drop(["Open","Adj Close", "Volume"], axis=1)
```

This way, I get two datasets with the same number of rows and time steps:

```
    >>> print(df_y,df_x)
            (Open, ^GSPC)
Date
1991-10-07     381.220001
1991-10-08     379.500000
1991-10-09     380.570007
1991-10-10     376.799988
1991-10-11     380.549988
...                   ...
2021-09-29    4362.410156
2021-09-30    4370.669922
2021-10-01    4317.160156
2021-10-04    4348.839844
2021-10-05    4309.870117

[7557 rows x 1 columns]                    Close                        High                         Low
                    DJIA         ^IXIC          DJIA         ^IXIC          DJIA         ^IXIC
Date
1991-10-07   2942.750000    516.200012   2973.169922    519.630005   2926.209961    515.940002
1991-10-08   2963.770020    517.250000   2983.679932    517.250000   2927.770020    514.809998
1991-10-09   2946.330078    513.809998   2984.790039    517.229980   2925.540039    513.799988
1991-10-10   2976.520020    515.940002   2985.469971    516.409973   2930.229980    513.210022
1991-10-11   2983.679932    519.049988   3000.889893    519.159973   2957.510010    517.159973
...                  ...           ...           ...           ...           ...           ...
2021-09-29  34390.718750  14512.440430  34580.421875  14676.620117  34305.960938  14493.669922
2021-09-30  33843.921875  14448.580078  34557.371094  14632.360352  33833.320312  14444.299805
2021-10-01  34326.460938  14566.700195  34490.558594  14606.820312  33785.539062  14324.009766
2021-10-04  34002.921875  14255.480469  34410.281250  14499.740234  33821.578125  14181.690430
2021-10-05  34314.671875  14433.830078  34490.949219  14508.650391  34035.250000  14299.780273

[7557 rows x 6 columns]
```

Now, the problem arises when I join the two datasets as follows and I get the following warning:

```
df=df_y.join(df_x)
UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)
```

I end up with this result which is fine:

```
>>> df
            (Open, ^GSPC)  (Close, DJIA)  (Close, ^IXIC)  (High, DJIA)  (High, ^IXIC)   (Low, DJIA)  (Low, ^IXIC)
Date
1991-10-07     381.220001    2942.750000      516.200012   2973.169922     519.630005   2926.209961    515.940002
1991-10-08     379.500000    2963.770020      517.250000   2983.679932     517.250000   2927.770020    514.809998
1991-10-09     380.570007    2946.330078      513.809998   2984.790039     517.229980   2925.540039    513.799988
1991-10-10     376.799988    2976.520020      515.940002   2985.469971     516.409973   2930.229980    513.210022
1991-10-11     380.549988    2983.679932      519.049988   3000.889893     519.159973   2957.510010    517.159973
...                   ...            ...             ...           ...            ...           ...           ...
2021-09-29    4362.410156   34390.718750    14512.440430  34580.421875   14676.620117  34305.960938  14493.669922
2021-09-30    4370.669922   33843.921875    14448.580078  34557.371094   14632.360352  33833.320312  14444.299805
2021-10-01    4317.160156   34326.460938    14566.700195  34490.558594   14606.820312  33785.539062  14324.009766
2021-10-04    4348.839844   34002.921875    14255.480469  34410.281250   14499.740234  33821.578125  14181.690430
2021-10-05    4309.870117   34314.671875    14433.830078  34490.949219   14508.650391  34035.250000  14299.780273
```

However, if I try to run any loop over the dataset columns, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

which I guess occurs because of the double indexing (Close, High, Low and stock tickers DJIA and ^IXIC). How can I fix this? I have found several methods to convert tuples to strings, but none of these apply to dataframe columns. I would like to keep the column name as printed above, since it makes it easier to distinguish between indices.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error and the relevant code causing it as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I create sample dataframes and made joining between them, and made loop for a specific column from the merged dataframe, and I don't face that problem.
Please clarify more about the problem.

```
f2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
f1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([[1, 43, 757], [4, 56, 76], [7, 756,57]])),columns=['a','h','r'])
f3 = f1.join(f1,on='a',how='left',lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
for i in f3['h_right']:
   print (i)
```